# Architecture of a spring boot application

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I'm currently working with a spring boot an angular 5 to develop a website, 
and the problem that I'm facing is that I read to many articles about the logical architecture of application and I don't know what to use.

Well for the angular 5 part, I know it uses the MVVM DP. 
but in the backeEnd, I'm not sure if it uses the MVC or not.

So this is who I have implemented it: I have a REST Controller acting as my Entry point, it call method on my service layer (extends for Interface of that service) and finally uses repository, I have one and only database.

Is this a RestFull SOA or MVC ?

Comment: Brother, you're all over the place. What is your question exactly the architecture of spring boot? What is MVC vs SOA? Front End VS Back End? Sounds like you're knee deep learning and you have your head wrapped around the concepts, you're doing good but your question is off the charts and to answer it would almost be like writing a short book. You should be specific with your questions and provide examples so that we can help you better.  If you tighten up the question, basically removing all of the other yamma jamma in it, and ask exactly what you want, then you can get a solid answer.

Comment: To make it simple i want to what is the logical architecture that will suit my needs. i just want to know, if i'm using Rest controller + Services + Repository what kind of logical architecture is this. keep in mind that i'm only using one database.

Comment: It sounds like you just need someone to have an opinion for you. Spring MVC / Spring Boot does some of this... but I'd really check out https://www.jhipster.tech/ <-- jHipster makes a good deal of choices automatically for you, and in some places asks your opinion about stuff you need (Angular or React?).